# Can I get contents of SQLite Database onto computer

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm very new to this android app development business and as an introduction to SQLite I thought I would create a simple survey app to record a persons name, age and favourite tv channel.  I was wondering though with the results that are recorded can these be exported to a computer to be analysed, for example to a text file, excel sheet, sql server table?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes, you can get them with an adb shell.

Comment: Thanks Darokthar.  I just had a quick look at adb shell.  Would I just use the pull command and the location of the db on the device?

Comment: In eclipse, [dmms Answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390331/android-sqlite-database-schema/14390405#14390405)

Comment: pull to get it from the device and push to send a file to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Check these posts:

**[Debugging sqlite database on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928849/debugging-sqlite-database-on-the-device)**

**[Access android sqlite database from development pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879471/access-android-sqlite-database-from-development-pc)**

**[Copy sqlite database from device to pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012255/copy-sqlite-database-from-device-to-pc)**

In the future **PLEASE do your homework** before asking a question.